# Does a resistance of filament lamp increase with increase of current?

Tags: electricity

As we know from the nonlinear I-V characteristics of a filament lamp, that the resistance of a filament changes with change in current/voltage.

[image]

From the relation V=IR, it should imply that, say with increase in current, the resistance should decrease, but at the same time V is increasing aswell. So, how to be certain that increase in V is more than that of I, such that R increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistance of a particular component is defined to be the applied voltage divided by the resulting current.  As you can see from the plot you attached, you can continue to increase V as much as you'd like, but the resulting current appears to saturate at some constant value.  Therefore, the ratio $R = V/I$ increases with increasing $V$.

Comment: So, this means, when I increase $I$, $V$ will increase by more amount, resulting in an increase in current, even with the increase of current. Ah, I get it.